# SaveFileDialog OverwritePrompt not Working

Tags: wpf, prism

In my WPF application, I want to get notified with an overwrite prompt, if I try to overwrite an existing file when I am saving a file.

This is the code which saves the file. 
In the savefiledialog options I am setting the Overwrite prompt to true, but this fails to work.

```
var dialogOptions = new SaveFileDialogOptions { Filter = Resources.SaveFileDialogFilter, OverwritePrompt = true};

var result = dialogService.SaveFile(dialogOptions, null);

if (result == true)
{
// Save the file
}
```

**DialogServices.cs**

```
public bool? SaveFile(SaveFileDialogOptions options, Window owner)
{

return ShowDialog<SaveFileDialogOptions, SaveFileDialog>(options, owner);

}

static bool? ShowDialog<TDialogOptions, TDialog>(TDialogOptions options, Window owner)
            where TDialogOptions : FileDialogOptions, new()
            where TDialog : FileDialog, new()
{

var dialog = new TDialog();
            PropertyCopy<TDialog>.CopyFrom(options, dialog);
            var result = owner == null ? dialog.ShowDialog() : dialog.ShowDialog(owner);
            PropertyCopy<TDialogOptions>.CopyFrom(dialog, options);
            return result;

}
```

pls answer if anyone knows, why this is not working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

SaveFileDialog.OverwritePrompt = false;